# moving array elements forward and inserting new element

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

Basically what I am trying to do is move all the elements in the array forward and then insert a new task into whatever location the user enters. The problem is `fgets` somehow is putting the new string the user enters into two locations. So when I print the whole array of tasks I will get this:

```
new task
new task(wake should be here)
2. eat
3. class
4. homework

instead of

new task
1. wake
2. eat
3. class
4. homework
```

I do not know why this is happening. When I just set the new task like this: `tasks[task_location] = "new task"`. The list comes out right. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong I have tried other things such as `scanf` but I still get the same issue.

```
#define elements_in_array 200
char** tasks;
FILE* fp;//fopen null check etc standard stuff i did too
tasks = (char**)malloc(elements_in_array * sizeof(char*));
for(i=0;i<elements_in_array;i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = malloc(tasks_entered * sizeof(char));
    }
while(!feof(fp))// counts lines
{
    c = fgetc(fp);
    if(c == '\n')
    {
        tasks_entered+=1;
        total_tasks = tasks_entered;
    }
}
rewind(fp);
for(i=0;i<tasks_entered;i++)//reads strings into array
{
    fgets(tasks[i],elements_in_array,fp);
}

printf("Where would you like to add this task?\n");
printf("Add task to #: ");
scanf("%d", &task_Location);
if(tasks_entered > total_tasks)
        {
            //i know i didnt realloc correctly but works for now
            tasks = realloc(tasks,tasks_entered*2);
            total_tasks = tasks_entered*2;
        }
for(i=tasks_entered-1;i>=task_Location-1;i--)
{
    tasks[i+1] = tasks[i];
}   
fgets (tasks[task_location], elements_in_array, stdin);
tasks_entered+=1;
```

Comment: If `tasks` is just an array of pointers, then you need to allocate memory for the input string before calling `fgets`. Please add the declaration of `tasks` to your question.

Comment: `task[i]=malloc(tasks_entered * sizeof(char));` seems suspicious to me. Are you sure you wanted `tasks_entered` there? Try `tasks[i]=malloc(100)` instead.

Comment: I am having trouble conceptualizing dynamic array allocation. What I was trying to do was make a 2d array where I could store strings(length of short sentences). For example arr[0] = "wake up", arr[1]= "eat some food", etc. So the basic idea is count lines in text file, then make the array large enough to hold the amount of lines that were in the text file. Unfortunately the assignment is to use a dynamically allocated array which is confusing me.

Comment: Try removing `!feof(fp)` and *move* `c = fgetc(fp)` there.

Comment: And you read strings into `task[i]` before you allocate memory for it.

Comment: I tried changing the feof thing but that didn't work caused errors and the counting lines part works fine. Also I when I was copying my code over just messed up the order. fixed the post thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @RonaldManganaro user338619's comment is definitely worthy of consideration. You need to look at it again more closely. And this: `fgets(tasks[i],elements_in_array,fp)` is definitely wrong unless `tasks_entered` is equivalent to `elements_in_array` at the time of the initial allocation of the `task[i]` assignments.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//#define elements_in_array 200 //Not necessary because the dynamically allocated

int main(void){
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    //Pre-read
    int c, count_char = 0, max_line_size = 0;
    int total_tasks, tasks_entered = 0;
    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        if(c == '\n'){
            tasks_entered += 1;
            if(max_line_size < count_char){
                max_line_size = count_char;
            }
            count_char = 0;//reset
        } else {
            count_char += 1;
        }
    }
    if(count_char > 0){
        tasks_entered += 1;
        if(max_line_size < count_char){
            max_line_size = count_char;
        }
    }
    char** tasks;
    total_tasks = tasks_entered;
    tasks = malloc(total_tasks * sizeof(char*));
    int buff_size = max_line_size + 2 + 16;//2: \n + \0, 16: reserve
    char *buffer = malloc(buff_size);
    rewind(fp);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<tasks_entered;i++){
        fgets(buffer, buff_size, fp);
        int len = strlen(buffer);
        if(buffer[len-1] == '\n')
            buffer[len-=1] = '\0';
        tasks[i] = malloc(len + 1);
        strcpy(tasks[i], buffer);
        printf("%d.%s\n", i+1, tasks[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    char *new_task, *p;
    printf("enter new task : ");
    fgets(buffer, buff_size, stdin);
    if(p = strchr(buffer, '\n'))
        *p = 0;//remove newline
    new_task = strdup(buffer);//malloc and copy

    int task_Location;
    printf("Where would you like to add this task?\n");
    printf("Add task to #(1-%d): ", tasks_entered+1);
    do {
        scanf("%d", &task_Location);
    } while(task_Location > total_tasks + 1);

    task_Location -= 1;//to zero origin
    tasks = realloc(tasks, (tasks_entered+1)*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=tasks_entered-1;i>=task_Location;i--){
        tasks[i+1] = tasks[i];
    }
    tasks[task_Location] = new_task;
    tasks_entered += 1;
    total_tasks = tasks_entered;
    for(i=0;i<tasks_entered;++i)
        printf("%d.%s\n", i+1, tasks[i]);

    //deallocate
    return 0;
}
```